# Spanish and english references in the same document

Tags: bibliographies, languages, spanish, english

How can I use references in spanish and english in the same document?
My document is mainly in spanish with 2 chapters in english, so I need to be able to change the references between chapters from "y" to "and".

```
\documentclass[11pt, spanish, singlespacing, headsepline,]    {PhDDoctoralThesis} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{palatino} 
\usepackage[maxbibnames=99,backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex} % 
\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{%
andothers        = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
andmore          = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
}
\addbibresource{/Users/Me/Documents/Bibtex/library.bib}
```

Thank you so much, I hope you can help me.

Comment: Ok, where did you get the file PhDDoctoralThesis.cls from?

Comment: from latextemplates.com

Comment: I am unfortunately not able to find a class with this exact name on latextemplates.com. The only thesis class on this site I was able to find is `MastersDoctoralThesis.cl`. https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis. Is it this one you are using?